# Search item in array at postgres using typeorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, express, typeorm

**Database**: postgres

**ORM**: Typeorm

**Framework**: express.js

I have a Table in which one of the fields, named `projects` is an array of strings. The type is set to `"varchar"` in the migration and the de decorator is set to `"simple-array"`.

In my get route if I receive a query `?project=name_of_the_project` it should try to find the project in the simple-array.

For the search my get route is like this:

```
studentsRouter.get("/", async (request, response) => {
    const { project } = request.query;
    const studentRepository = getCustomRepository(StudentRepository);
    const students = project
        ? await studentRepository
                .createQueryBuilder("students")
                .where(":project = ANY (students.projects)", { project: project })
                .getMany()
        : await studentRepository.find();
    // const students = await studentRepository.find();
    return response.json(students);
});
```

The problem is that I´m getting an error saying that the right side should be an array.

```
(node:38971) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
    at new QueryFailedError (/Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
    at Query.callback (/Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:178:30)
    at Query.handleError (/Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:146:19)
    at Connection.connectedErrorMessageHandler (/Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:233:17)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at /Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:10
    at Parser.parse (/Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:102:9)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
(node:38971) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:38971) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It has to be an array of string in this field and I can´t use an foreignKey.

Please find bellow my migration and model related to this issue:

**Migration**:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Table } from "typeorm";

export class CreateStudents1594744103410 implements MigrationInterface {
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.createTable(
            new Table({
                name: "students",
                columns: [
                    {
                        name: "id",
                        type: "uuid",
                        isPrimary: true,
                        generationStrategy: "uuid",
                        default: "uuid_generate_v4()",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "name",
                        type: "varchar",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "intra_id",
                        type: "varchar",
                        isUnique: true,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "projects",
                        type: "varchar",
                        isNullable: true,
                    },
                ],
            })
        );
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.dropTable("students");
    }
}
```

**Model**:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity("students")
class Student {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    intra_id: string;

    @Column("simple-array")
    projects: string[];
}

export default Student;
```

**EDIT - 01**

In the docs I found out that the `simple-array` stores the strings separated by a comma. I thing this means it is a string with words separated by a comma. In this case is there a way to find the which row has the string in the projects field?

Link - https://gitee.com/mirrors/TypeORM/blob/master/docs/entities.md#column-types-for-postgres

**Edit 02**

The field projects stores the projects that the students are doing, so the database returns this json:

```
  {
    "id": "e586d1d8-ec03-4d29-a823-375068de23aa",
    "name": "First Lastname",
    "intra_id": "flastname",
    "projects": [
      "42cursus_libft",
      "42cursus_get-next-line",
      "42cursus_ft-printf"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: It looks like column `projects` should have datatype `varchar[]` (or `text[]`) rather than just `varchar`.

Comment: @GMB , I tryied this and I got the same error.

Comment: What is actually stored in `projects`?  Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Can you query the database directly?  What your ORM is producing is not helpful because it is formatted.  There is a function you can try:  `.where(":project = ANY ( string_to_array(students.projects, ','))", { project: project })` You may need to adjust the delimiter to what the ORM is using.

Comment: @MikeOrganek , it worked! Please give an answer so I can check.

Comment: Thank you!  Good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments and updates to the question, @WincentyBertoniLech determined that the ORM was storing the `projects` array as a comma-delimited text value in the `students.projects` column.

We can use `string_to_array()` to turn this into the proper `where` criterion:

```
.where(":project = ANY ( string_to_array(students.projects, ','))", { project: project })
```